# jQuery click event on $(this)

Tags: jquery

This is my testcase:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $('.sequence').on('click', function()
      {
        e = $(this).next(); // div element, DOM element
        e.html(Math.random());

        e.on('click', function()
        {       
          e.html(Math.random());
        });

      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="sequence">Sequence 1</div>
    <div>1</div>

    <div class="sequence">Sequence 2</div>
    <div>2</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Upper code can be tested on http://jsfiddle.net/3LrXZ.

When I click on div **Sequence 1**, next div which first has text '1' gets some random value let us say 0.3126203578431159. Then I click on div **Sequence 2** and next div which initially has value '2' gets some random value let us say 0.16280379495583475. Till now everything works as it should. **Now** when I click on the first 0.3126203578431159 the second div 0.16280379495583475 changes value. Element 0.312620357843115 should change value (get new random, not the second one).

Does this mean that you can not bind events on DOM element, that you can only bind events on html element id, class, some other attribute? Does't each DOM element has also some ID, which can be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scoping issue. Your undeclared `e` becomes a global that is shared between both handlers. To fix it:

```
var e = $(this).next();
```

This will have an unique `e` inside each sequence' handler.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LrXZ/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Nice catch because i have hard time to find what was the issue. I should read code first before testing

Comment: Fabrício Matté thank you for this. I did not know that this was scoping problem. Thank you again.

Comment: @broadband no problem, just note that often binding a handler inside of another event handler may be inefficient, for example in this case, everytime you click a `.sequence` another click handler is added to its next element, so when you click that next element it will execute 2 randomizations. It is unnoticeable at first, but in case you'd do heavy work in that handler, you'd notice a performance loss. So `e.off('click').on('click', ...)` can be used to prevent attaching multiple handlers in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var e = $(this).next(); // div element, DOM element
      e.html(Math.random());          

      e.on('click', function ()
      {
          $(this).html(Math.random());
      });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59HgA/

Comment: +1 this is a valid solution, though it'd be better if you commented on the code's issue(s) - "give a man a fish and he will eat for day, teach he how to fish and he may devastate the ecosystem" or something like that.